# How do I know if my site is not using material design?

Tags: material-design, enterprise

I checked on google's [design site](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#), but couldn't find a comprehensive spec on this. There are only goals, principals and guidelines. In fact, in most websites I had searched there are only **do's** of material design, there are no **don'ts**.

That got me thinking about

- how do I know what is missing from my site for it be certified as an app on material design?
- how do I know that my app is not already on material design?

Someone told me that UX team these days put material design as their top priority and mandate that all websites should be on material design before it even come for review to them. So, I want to understand clearly when is an app not on material design.

Comment: ux teams most definitely do NOT make material design a priority. It's an option, but not in anyway better or worse than a multitude of other options. As for 'material design certification' I don't know who would do that or what value that would even bring to the users of your site.

Comment: thanks @DA01. I am not looking for an external certification rather want to understand 'don'ts of material design' myself.

Comment: Please leave a comment/reason for downvotes.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it look like people are thinking this is just too broad. I tend to agree. There really aren't a list of "don'ts" for Material Design. It's just a set of guidelines that you should be free to use as you see fit.

Comment: @DA01 In that case `There are no specs and don'ts of material design` is also an acceptable reply. But how do I know that my app is already not on material design. And if not, then what is missing from it? I don't think this is too broad a question. Someone who knows material design should also know what is not a material design, and should be able to tell why. If it is too broad, can you help me in making it less broad? Thanks

Comment: From a UX perspective, I'd ask "why does it matter?". From a technical perspective, there is no officiating body to grant your app any sort of official material design status. Whether an app is considered 'material design' is going to be as much about subjective opinions as it is objective.

Comment: @DA01 I don't know if it matters at all for UX point of view. But UX teams are pushing for it and they are going to certify the apps as 'okay' for user, so I would like to know about more it before blindly following them.

Comment: In that case, you need to ask this question to the UX team you are working with, as the only answer that will matter is theirs if they are the ones 'certifying' it.

Comment: @DA01 off course I will, but I also want to know what experts on this site think about it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33557/discussion-between-da01-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit hard to answer. I actually don't know if there is certification on material design, if you can share this information, that will be great.

I had chance yo attended google launchpad day couple weeks ago, this is what I takeaway;

Material design is a "paper" foundation with make sense motions. It should act as paper as in physical world. Ex: if you take 2 piece of papers and lay one to the other, you should see very lightly shadow and the depth should calculate as such, if you increase the distance between 2 papers.  Since its paper concept, you should expect lots of negative spaces.

Motion is whats fun in material design, motion should make sense too, a btn trigger to enlarge a window from right hand bottom then when the window is set to close, it should shirk down the way it get enlarge but reversely.

You should check google codeslab.io , they have some solid resource to let u play with material design, else read google design guide inside out like me. :)

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks Chia_tea, appreciate your inputs. But I think I will have to close this question since it is perceived as too broad by experts on this site.

Comment: Fair enough and I agree as well.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2015/05/flat-design-vs-material-design-what-makes-them-different.html) by dreamweaver team suggest that difference between material design and flat design (older approach) is the introduction of z-axis.

> Material design may be aesthetically flat, specifically the colors,
>   but it is multi-dimensional: it takes the Z-axis into consideration.

Also as per [google's guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/material-properties.html#) a `material` is always suppose to have a uniform thickness of 1dp

> Material has varying x & y dimensions (measured in dp) and a uniform
>   thickness (1dp).
>
> Promotes motion in design … which means that you have to implement it
>   in order to make your creation true material design.

Interaction with material should be registered and trigger a subtle change in the state of material such as pressing of button, focus on a textbox, etc. So, if your button doesn't changes its state on being pressed then you are probably still on the earlier flat design approach.

As per a quote on [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) by Martias Duarte (Google's Director of Android User Experience),

> Material has physical surfaces and edges. Seams and shadows provide
>   meaning about what you can touch.

Google [implemented material design in gmail app](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8207/google-reveals-details-about-android-l-at-google-io) by removing unnecessary borders and lines (some of them are reduced only to a portion of the screen), and there is less information shown to make it cleaner.